# Putting a barcode in a Marketing Cloud email

Tags: event, marketing-cloud, barcode

I want to add a barcode to an email. 
Currently we use Eventsforce, which has a ticket layout creator. It adds the six digit personal ID written in the standard Code 39 barcode font. When this person attends the event, they will be scanned by our staff who have barcode scanners.

We have imported event attendees into Marketing Cloud from Eventsforce, Personal ID and all, and we would also like to send event attendees their tickets, with a barcode.

Is there any way of doing this, that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [**BarCodeURL()**](https://ampscript.guide/barcodeurl) AMPScript function:

```
<img style="width: 400px;" alt="WHEE" src='%%=BarCodeURL('WHEE','Code39', 400, 200, 0)=%%' width="400">
```

Reference:

[**AMPScript Function List**](https://ampscript.guide/function-index)

Comment: Many thanks, was not aware of a barcode function in Ampscript.